# Know if there are pending requests - GrapqhQl

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

OLD QUESTION:

I need to know if there are fetches in pending to set the spinner.
I'm doing it with watchQuery hook but it can manage only the networkStatus of a single fetch.

My code:

```
const client = useApolloClient()

const query = client.watchQuery({
    query: GET_DETTAGLIO_PUNTO_VENDITA,
    variables: {idPuntoVendita: idPuntoVendita ? Number(idPuntoVendita) : null},
})

useEffect(() => {
    query.reobserve().then((queryResponse) => {
        setQueryNetworkStatus(queryResponse.networkStatus)
    })
}, [query])
```

I want to intercept from graphQl cache or something else if there are one or more fethces in pending.
How can I do it ?

---

NEW QUESTION:

I found a solution but it don't work if I reload the page.

In my component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { middlewareLink, getPendingRequests } = createPendingRequestsLink();
    const link = ApolloLink.from([middlewareLink, client.link]);

    client.setLink(link);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setPendingRequests(getPendingRequests());
    }, 50);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
}, [client])
```

In another file:

```
  export const createPendingRequestsLink = () => {
    let pendingRequests = 0;

    const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    pendingRequests++;

    return new Observable((observer) => {
        const subscription = forward(operation).subscribe({
            next: observer.next.bind(observer),
            error: observer.error.bind(observer),
            complete: () => {
                observer.complete();
                pendingRequests--;
            },
        });

        return () => {
            if (subscription) subscription.unsubscribe();
        };
      });
    });

    return {middlewareLink, getPendingRequests: () => pendingRequests};
    };
```

If I reload the page pendingRequest variable don't update.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using the `useQuery` hook that would also give you that information?

Comment: Yes, I'm using useQuery in a specific component and I need the loading in another component. The components are at the same level so I cant pass it as prop.

Comment: Instead of passing it as a prop, you can use the Context hook to have it available to both.  [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) is the official documentation on the useContext hook.

Comment: @AlbertoManuguerra You could use that `useQuery` hook in both components to get the loading state.

Comment: @phry with useQuery I can't get pending status from more response.

Comment: But it returns a `networkStatus`?

Comment: it returns the pending requests number